# Kotlin @Deprecated ReplaceWith change function to variable assignment

Tags: kotlin

I have the following function extension that I want to Deprecate

```
fun <T : View> T.setVisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Deprecated Usage:

```
myTextView.setVisible(true)
```

New Usage:

```
myTextView.isVisible = true
```

I'm trying write a @Deprecated ReplaceWith expression that will auto fix this deprecation.  I tried the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
@Deprecated("Use Android KTX isVisible", replaceWith = ReplaceWith("isVisible = visible", "androidx.core.view.isVisible"))
fun <T : View> T.setVisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

When I Alt+ENTER on the 'myTextView.setVisible(true)' and select 'Replace with isVisible = visible' from the popup, it just deletes my deprecated code

Is there an ReplaceWith expression that I can use to auto fix my code (changing a function call to an assignment)?

Comment: Annoyingly reproduced in IntelliJ 2018.1 and 2019.1. This is most likely a bug, and I've opened an issue ([KT-30855](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30855)) to get some clarity on this. The weird part is that function to function or field to field works fine and replaces correctly, but the type conversion seems to break it.

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile here are some workarounds until the related bugs are fixed, all with there own specific drawbacks:

1. replace with a useless cast:

   ```
   ReplaceWith("(this as T).isVisible = visible")
   ```

   which will transform your code to:

   ```
   (myTextView as View).isVisible = true
   ```

   An IDE may warn you that this cast is not needed, which you could fix in a second step
2. using something like `also`

   ```
   ReplaceWith("also { it.isVisible = visible }")
   ```

   which transforms your code to:

   ```
   myTextView.also { it.isVisible = true }
   ```

   This code will probably not cause any warnings in your IDE, however it is clearly longer then needed
3. similar as to before, but using `apply`:

   ```
   ReplaceWith("apply { this@apply.isVisible = visible }")
   // leading to:
   myTextView.apply { isVisible = true }
   ```

These workarounds are only really helpful, if you have no other way to easily change the callers code and want to give your callers some help to replace that deprecated code which doesn't instantly delete the most important information ;-) If you have access to the callers code, then you are probably better off just replacing it ~manually ;-)

Comment: Nice solution, I just preffer `ReplaceWith("this as REMOVE_THIS_PART_WITH_AS.isVisible = value", "androidx.core.view.isVisible")` and after remove in whole project: ` as REMOVE_THIS_PART_WITH_AS` which will create valid code again.